# Why does twilios call forwarding not work when I am calling through browser, but work fine when calling a twilio number with exact same request url

Tags: python, django, twilio, pythonanywhere

I have one phone number with a request url which works (speaks the text and then forwards the call) but then I have an app (a browser outbound call) going to the same request url and only the text to speech works, and the forwarding of the call gives an error and hangs up. Why doesn't it forward like the number's request url? I checked and the capability token renders fine...

views.py

```
def once_connected_view(request):
    response = twiml.Response()
    response.say("Please wait while we connect your call.", voice='alice')
    response.dial("xxx-xx-xxx-xxxx")
    return HttpResponse(str(response))

def home_view(request):
    capability = TwilioCapability(account_sid, auth_token)
    capability.allow_client_outgoing(application_sid)
    token = capability.generate()
    query_set = Model.objects.all()
    return render(request, "base.html", {"query_set":query_set, "token":token})
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.home_view, name="home"),
    url(r'^once_connected/', views.once_connected_view, name="once_connected"),
]
```

number request url

http://xx.xx.com/once_connected/  http GET

app request url

http://xx.xx.com/once_connected/  http GET

main site url

https://xx.xx.com/

base.html

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://static.twilio.com/libs/twiliojs/1.2/twilio.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=320, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=medium-dpi" />
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'cars/responsive.css' %}">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container" id="wrapper">
  <div class="video-background-container">
    <video preload="auto" autoplay="" loop="" muted="" class="video-background hidden-xs hidden-sm">
      <source type="video/mp4" src="omitted">
    </video>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-overlay text-center">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" style="background:none;">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" id="logo" href="#">Brand Name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="replace-call"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Contact Us</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    ...
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    /* Create the Client with a Capability Token */
    Twilio.Device.setup("{{ token }}");

    /* Let us know when the client is ready. */
    Twilio.Device.ready(function (device) {
        $(".replace-call").html("<a href='#' onclick='call()'>Call From Browser</a>");
    });

    /* Report any errors on the screen */
    Twilio.Device.error(function (error) {
        $(".replace-call").html('<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Contact Us</a>');
    });

    Twilio.Device.connect(function (conn) {
        $(".replace-call").html("<a href='#' onclick='hangup()'>End Call</a>");
    });

    /* Connect to Twilio when we call this function. */
    function call() {
        Twilio.Device.connect();
    }
    function hangup() {
        Twilio.Device.disconnectAll();
        $(".replace-call").html('<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Contact Us</a>');
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am hosted on pythonanywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After only minimal hair loss, I have made it work by adding a callerID attribute to the dial verb.

```
def once_connected_view(request):
    response = twiml.Response()
    response.say("Please wait while we connect your call.", voice='alice')
    response.dial("xxx-xx-xxx-xxxx", callerId="+xxxxxxxxxx") #  here
    return HttpResponse(str(response))
```